# Permission Access Image/ Video Android 13 [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using package images_picker and update platform to sdk 33, I had update permission in my app and lib also but this is not working. The extension throw popup "Read memory card access denied" seems like permission not grantted, but i check in app info had permissions access photo and image.

- this is all permisson i denfine in manifest
  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exYW6.)
- and when app run first time i request permissions + action access all file:
  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v75ZR.png)
- then when i pick image/video the result is "Read memory card access denied"
  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv0Ws.png)

  flutter doctor:

```html
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm, locale en-VN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing images and videos from gallery/camera will be same in Android 13 as we get in iOS device with flutter,

```
class MyPermissionHandler {
  static Future<bool> checkPermission(
    BuildContext context, {
    String permissionName = 'gallery',
  }) async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
      if (sdkInt < 33 && permissionName == 'gallery') {
        return true;
      }
    }
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statues;
    switch (permissionName) {
      case 'camera':
        {
          statues = await [Permission.camera].request();
          PermissionStatus? statusCamera = statues[Permission.camera];
          if (statusCamera == PermissionStatus.granted) {
            return true;
          } else if (statusCamera == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
            showPermissionDialog(context, permissionName);
            return false;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      case 'gallery':
        {
          statues = await [Permission.photos].request();
          PermissionStatus? statusPhotos = statues[Permission.photos];
          if (statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.granted) {
            return true;
          } else if (statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
            showPermissionDialog(context, permissionName);
            return false;
          } else if (statusPhotos == PermissionStatus.limited) {
            showLimitedPermissionDialog(context, permissionName);
            return false;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

If will first request, if the user denies it will ask again to get access, but then after the user reject access permission 2nd time, you need to show the `showDialog` pop-up to open the setting and give access from the settings.

One more thing, the android version which is less than 13 will check with package device info `import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';` device info, previous device will be same and updated will be act like that.

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
      if (sdkInt < 33 && permissionName == 'gallery') {
        return true;
      }
    }
```